# wlan0 doesn't exist

Tags: wireless

I'm beginner in linux and have some troubles with wi fi settings.
I installed ubuntu on my laptop with windows. Installation was successfully, however i couldnt connect to my home wifi. I looked for solution for 2 days but it haven't work yet. I installed ndiswrapper, downloaded ALL my windows network drivers in kernel (by modprobe) but wlan0 interface in iwconfig didn't appear. Here are some logs:

iwconfig

```
    eth0      no wireless extensions.

    lo        no wireless extensions.
```

lspci -nn

```
   00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller         [8086:0a04] (rev 0b)
   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT    Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b)
   00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller [8086:0a0c] (rev 0b)
   00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0a03] (rev 0b)
   00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC [8086:9c31] (rev 04)
   00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 [8086:9c3a] (rev 04)
   00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller [8086:9c20] (rev 04)
   00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:9c10] (rev e4)
   00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:9c14] (rev e4)
   00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:9c16] (rev e4)
   00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:9c18] (rev e4)
   00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 [8086:9c26] (rev 04)
   00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9c43] (rev 04)
   00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8086:9c03] (rev 04)
   00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller [8086:9c22] (rev 04)
   00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP Thermal [8086:9c24] (rev 04)
   02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
   03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
   04:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] [10de:1341] (rev a2)
```

Plz help me